# Partition data based on condition ("where") in a single query?

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data that I need to partition based on some condition, i.e.:

```
var trues  = from item in items where  MyCondition(item, blah) select item;
var falses = from item in items where !MyCondition(item, blah) select item;
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this in a single query and get both results back so that I don't have to repeat myself (and end up iterating over the data twice) like above?

Comment: You can group by the condition.

Comment: Any particular reason to avoid classic foreach loop ?

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: It's not as clean. If I go that route, I might as well not use LINQ in the first place...

Comment: @NicoSchertler: How do you recommend extracting `trues` and `falses` after grouping them into `grouped`?

Comment: How would you like your results? As IEnumerable<T> or as List<T>?

Comment: @dtb: Two `IEnumerable<T>`s (one `trues`, one `falses`).

Comment: Where is the answer that was posted some minutes ago? That was exactly what you need, wasn't it?

Comment: @NicoSchertler: The owner deleted it, probably because (as I was just about to point out) it didn't actually work -- you can't index it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to iterate over the data twice, you will have to create a LINQ query that contains the true values and the false values with an indicator to which group they belong.

You can do this using a `ToLookup`:

```
var combined = items.ToLookup(x => MyCondition(x, blah));
var trues = combined[true];
var falses = combined[false];
```

Comment: What happens if none of them happen to satisfy the condition?

Comment: `trues` and `falses` will be empty enumerables. A lookup doesn't throw an exception if it doesn't contain any items with the specified key - it returns an empty enumerable instead.

Comment: Why not `var combined = items.ToLookup(x => MyCondition(x, blah));`?

Comment: @dtb: You are right, that's the correct version to use. Fixed my answer.